# Problem outputting dynamic array from function

Tags: c++

the function is to preserve argument array and produce anidentical array in the heap memory that has the even elements to (left) & odd(right), but when i  output i find a row of zeros and bunch of random big numbers which look like addresses but I don't think they are, Please help.

```
    int* even_left_odd_right(int arr[], int size1)
{
    int* array;
    array = new int[size1];

    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        array[i] = arr[i];

    for(int i = 0, j =0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return  array;
}

int main()
{

    int size1;
    cout << "Enter size of array:";
    cin >> size1;

    int* array1;
    array1 = new int[size1];
    
    int arr[size1];

    cout << "Enter the entries in this array: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    even_left_odd_right(arr, size1);

    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        cout << array1[i] << " ";
        delete[] array1;
            
        return 0;
    }`
```

Comment: `array1` inside `main()` is not the same as `array1` inside your function. You need to use the value returned from your function. Also, `int arr[size1]` is NOT valid c++

Comment: `int arr[size1];` -- If this was allowed in C++, why even use `new[]` and `delete[]` when all you would need is to declare the array with a varying size?

Comment: *produce an identical array in the heap memory that has the even elements to (left) & odd(right)* -- Just FYI -- `std::stable_partition(array1, array1 + size, [&](int n) { return n%2==0; });` -- does this work.  But I suspect this is homework, and you have to implement this from scratch.

Comment: You have two different arrays called `array1`, and one of them is discarded prior to deletion; this is a memory leak. I recommend researching local variables and scope. You also attempt to create a variable length array (VLA) on the stack. VLAs are not allowed in C++; you should research this as well. With proper research, you'll likely find the answer to your own question.

Comment: Hey @PaulMcKenzie, I am new to coding, i dont know what u meant, int arr[size] was how we initialized the size and the array, can u please explain, and this was a quiz question that failed to get a result for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of all your problems is that you do not use the return value of your function. Besides that, there are more things that should be corrected.

Additionally, we need to mention that what you are obviously learning now, dynamic memory management using `new` and `delete` and raw pointers for owned memory, is strongly discourage.

Basically: `new`, `delete` and raw pointers for owned memory should NEVER be used in C++.

It is that error prone that is has no place any more in standard C++. You even have an error with leaked memory and do not notice it. The array, that you are dynamically allocating in your function with new, is never deleted.

I know that teachers still do teach this crap, but just for explaining dynamic memory mangement from scratch. So, let's go ahead and use it for now.

You have however some additional errors.

- Your function returns the partitioned data. But you never use the functions return value
- You are using (for whatever reason??) a so called VLA (Variable Length Array) in `int arr[size1];`. This is illegal in C++. Real C++ compilers will not allow that.
- You are mixing up `arr` and `array1`. In the beginning, you are creating `array1`. After creation, it is not initialized and will contain random values.
- Then you call your function with `arr` and output `array1` at the end. So, you will output random data. That is, what you see. Random data.
- You could use the build in `std::swap` function. But I guess that it is prohibited by the teacher. What a shame.
- You unneccessarily change the order of the entries in the array with swapping. But this does not harm
- Your function simply returns a raw pointer. The outer world does not know anything about that. That is dangerous
- You even do not know that `arr` in your function signature (`int arr[]`) will decay to a pointer

To quickly fix your code, we could write:

```
#include <iostream>

int* even_left_odd_right(int arr[], int size1)
{
    int* array;
    array = new int[size1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        array[i] = arr[i];

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            int temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return  array;
}

int main()
{

    int size1;
    std::cout << "Enter size of array:";
    std::cin >> size1;

    int* array1;
    array1 = new int[size1];

    //int arr[size1];  NOT ALLOWED in C++

    std::cout << "Enter the entries in this array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        std::cin >> array1[i];

    int* array2 = even_left_odd_right(array1, size1);

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        std::cout << array2[i] << " ";

    delete [] array1;
    delete [] array2;

    return 0;
}
```

But such code should never be used in C++.

Again, I guess I understand requirements from teacher.

By the way. In C++17 you would probaly write the follwoing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // Tell user, what to do: Get the number of data to operate on
    std::cout << "\nEnter the number of data to operate on: ";

    // Read the number of data from the user via std::cin. Check, if number is OK
    if (size_t numberOfData{}; (std::cin >> numberOfData) and (numberOfData > 0)) {

        // Define the vector for our original data with the size given by the user
        std::vector<int> dataOriginal(numberOfData);

        // And get the number of specified data from the user
        std::cout << "\n\nAnd now, please enter the data\n";
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfData, dataOriginal.begin());

        // We want to preserve the original input, so, make a copy of that vector
        std::vector result(dataOriginal);

        // Now partition the output as requested
        std::stable_partition(result.begin(), result.end(), [](const int i) { return (i % 2) == 0; });

        // Show result to user
        std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\nError: Wrong input given for number of data\n\n";
    }
}
```

Please note:

- No loops
- Input validation
- CTAD
- No function needed, everthing can be done with one statemennt